# SQLAlchemy override reflected columns dynamically

Tags: mysql, reflection, sqlalchemy, python-2.7

I'm using SA in a script I'll be using to periodically 'copy' a subset of mysql tables from a 'production' replica to dev/test systems. I had written code to simply reflect the source tables and `meta.create_all(destination_engine)`. Due to the nature of FKs, I now know I need to apply `use_alter=True` to the ForeignKeys on the tables as I create them so that I won't get CircularDependencyErrors or other problems. I need to assume I dont know how many FK's or their names until I go through the metadata.

I'm new to SA and typically Java programmer (as you will tell :D). I tried to change the use_alter attr. iteratively at first:

```
tablesd = smeta.tables.items()
for tname, t in tablesd:
    for c in t.columns:
       for fk in c.foreign_keys:
            fk.use_alter = True
smeta.create_all(to_engine)
```

**EDIT:** It's important to note that create_all() does NOT throw a CircularDependencyError after I set the use_alter property like I do above. If I remove that code, create_all() does not work. It just doesnt seem to be removing the FKs from the create...

This obviously didn't work. I then read [Overriding Reflected Columns](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/schema.html#overriding-reflected-columns) in the SA docs, sample being:

```
mytable = Table('mytable', meta,
Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True), # override reflected 'id' to have primary key
Column('mydata', Unicode(50)),    # override reflected 'mydata' to be Unicode,   autoload=True)
```

I'd guess reflecting each table individually then adding `use_alter=True` in the FK definition would work, but I CANNOT assume the names and values or # of FK's/columns. I read a lot about using `DeclarativeBase` to do something like this, but I'm not really sure how that would work...

How can I take my arbitrary list of tables, reflect them, then Override the use_alter option on their respective foreign keys? Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer ended up being inside the problem (Imagine that...). Although each `ForeignKey` object has a `use_alter` value that can be set, `Constraints` also have a separate property that can be set (I was not able to find this in the [API Documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/schema.html#constraints-api). After running it through PyDev's Debugger, I noticed the former were being set, but all the keys that had `Constraints` associated with them were still `False`. I set them to true thusly:

```
for fk in table.foreign_keys:
    fk.use_alter=True
    fk.constraint.use_alter=True
```

This seemed to produce the SQL I was looking for and tables were created correctly with no `CircularDependencyErrors` and `metadata.sorted_tables` seemed to work fine with no errors. I was actually able to refactor my code and do things the *RIGHT* way!

For anyone looking to do DB-->DB reflecting with complex FKs using SQLAlchemy, this answer and [Tyler Lesmann's article](http://www.tylerlesmann.com/2009/apr/27/copying-databases-across-platforms-sqlalchemy/) are for you.

**UPDATE: ** Using this method has passed a peer review and is now being used as production code. Seems to work well!